# React native Ios release with only main.jsbundle and asset file

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Hello can we publish React Native IOS app on app store with just `main.jsbundle` file?
when we create IOS release we needed to bundle file that is copy inside IOS archive that is released to app store.

I tried coping it manually but it keeps generating from the react native code. i can't move it to pre-bundle main.jsbundle. i have copy this file to `ios/main.jsbundle` and also try to copy to `DrivedData` folder.